Upgrade maven 3.0.3 to latest available 3.9.9 version (java-8 supported version)
I am trying to upgrade maven version in my project from 3.0.3 to maven 3.9.9
The project has its own private repository from where it tries to resolve the dependencies, the maven command to resolve the dependencies throws error while resolving only few dependencies
mvn -U -f /home/example-pom.xml -s /home/settings.xml dependency:resolve -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""

The example-pom.xml consists of various submodules and looks like this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.project-example</groupId>
  <artifactId>examples</artifactId>
  <name>examples</name>
  <description>example pom</description>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.project-example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-base</artifactId>
    <version>24.3.25.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://private-repository.com/mavenrepo/24.3.25.0.2/repository</url>
      <releases>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>https://private-repository.com/mavenrepo/24.3.25.0.2/repository</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.project-example</groupId>
      <artifactId>example-subproject1</artifactId>
      <version>24.3.25.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
<project>

one of the submodule contains dependency org.infinispan:infinispan-core:jar:9.3.0.Final

settings.xml file looks like below

<settings>
    <interactiveMode>false</interactiveMode>
    <localRepository>/usr/local/examples/mavenrepo</localRepository>
    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <active>false</active>
            <protocol>https</protocol>
            <username/>
            <password/>
            <port>80</port>
            <host>127.0.0.1</host>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>central</id>
            <configuration>
                <httpHeaders>
                    <property>
                        <name>Authorization</name>
                        <value>Basic xxxx</value>
                    </property>
                </httpHeaders>
            </configuration>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <mirrors/>
    <profiles/>
</settings>

Instead of resolving through the private repository it goes to the maven central which is blocked in the system environment hence throws the below build error
Apache Maven 3.9.9 (8e8579a9e76f7d015ee5ec7bfcdc97d260186937)
Maven home: /usr/local/maven
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:resolve on project examples: Could not collect dependencies for project com.project-example:examples:pom:24.3.25.0.2-SNAPSHOT
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.infinispan:infinispan-core:jar:9.3.0.Final
Caused by: The following artifacts could not be resolved: io.netty:netty-bom:pom:4.1.22.Final (absent): Could not transfer artifact io.netty:netty-bom:pom:4.1.22.Final from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: Could not build a validated path

However, when I tried to debug further and delete the netty-bom dependency manually from mavenrepo, and ran the dependency:get command below
mvn -U -X -f /home/example-pom.xml -s /home/settings.xml dependency:get -DgroupId=io.netty -DartifactId=netty-bom -Dversion=4.1.22.Final -Dpackaging=pom -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""

It successfully resolves the dependency from the remote repository
but, when deleting the infinispan dependencies and running the dependency:get command, It gave the below debug trace
mvn -U -X -f /home/example-pom.xml -s /home/settings.xml dependency:get -DgroupId=org.infinispan -DartifactId=infinispan-core -Dversion=9.3.0.Final -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""


[INFO] Downloading from central: https://private-repository.com/mavenrepo/24.3.25.0.2/repositoryorg/infinispan/infinispan-core/9.3.0.Final/infinispan-core-9.3.0.Final.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://private-repository.com/mavenrepo/24.3.25.0.2/repositoryorg/infinispan/infinispan-core/9.3.0.Final/infinispan-core-9.3.0.Final.pom (9.9 kB at 194 kB/s)
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file '/usr/local/examples/mavenrepo/org/infinispan/infinispan-core/9.3.0.Final/_remote.repositories'
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file '/usr/local/examples/mavenrepo/org/infinispan/infinispan-core/9.3.0.Final/infinispan-core-9.3.0.Final.pom.lastUpdated'
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact org.infinispan:infinispan-bom:pom:9.3.0.Final from [central (https://private-repository.com/mavenrepo/24.3.25.0.2/repository, default, releases+snapshots)]
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact org.infinispan:infinispan-bom:pom:9.3.0.Final from [central (https://private-repository.com/mavenrepo/24.3.25.0.2/repository, default, releases+snapshots)]
[DEBUG] Using transporter HttpTransporter with priority 5.0 for https://private-repository.com/mavenrepo/24.3.25.0.2/repository
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://private-repository.com/mavenrepo/24.3.25.0.2/repository
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://private-repository.com/mavenrepo/24.3.25.0.2/repositoryorg/infinispan/infinispan-bom/9.3.0.Final/infinispan-bom-9.3.0.Final.pom
[INFO] Downloaded from central: https://private-repository.com/mavenrepo/24.3.25.0.2/repositoryorg/infinispan/infinispan-bom/9.3.0.Final/infinispan-bom-9.3.0.Final.pom (33 kB at 456 kB/s)
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file '/usr/local/examples/mavenrepo/org/infinispan/infinispan-bom/9.3.0.Final/_remote.repositories'
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file '/usr/local/examples/mavenrepo/org/infinispan/infinispan-bom/9.3.0.Final/infinispan-bom-9.3.0.Final.pom.lastUpdated'
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact io.netty:netty-bom:pom:4.1.22.Final from [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact io.netty:netty-bom:pom:4.1.22.Final from [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Using transporter HttpTransporter with priority 5.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-bom/4.1.22.Final/netty-bom-4.1.22.Final.pom
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file '/usr/local/examples/mavenrepo/io/netty/netty-bom/4.1.22.Final/netty-bom-4.1.22.Final.pom.lastUpdated'
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.6 from [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.6 from [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Using transporter HttpTransporter with priority 5.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-bom/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-bom-1.2.6.pom
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file '/usr/local/examples/mavenrepo/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/shrinkwrap-bom/1.2.6/shrinkwrap-bom-1.2.6.pom.lastUpdated'
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom:pom:2.0.0-alpha-10 from [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom:pom:2.0.0-alpha-10 from [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Using transporter HttpTransporter with priority 5.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom/2.0.0-alpha-10/shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom-2.0.0-alpha-10.pom
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file '/usr/local/examples/mavenrepo/org/jboss/shrinkwrap/descriptors/shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom/2.0.0-alpha-10/shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom-2.0.0-alpha-10.pom.lastUpdated'
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact io.netty:netty-bom:pom:4.1.22.Final from [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact io.netty:netty-bom:pom:4.1.22.Final from [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for io.netty:netty-bom:pom:4.1.22.Final, already updated during this session
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.6 from [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.6 from [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.6, already updated during this session
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom:pom:2.0.0-alpha-10 from [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Resolving artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom:pom:2.0.0-alpha-10 from [central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, default, releases)]
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom:pom:2.0.0-alpha-10, already updated during this session
[WARNING] Failed to build parent project for org.infinispan:infinispan-core:bundle:9.3.0.Final
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: The following artifacts could not be resolved: io.netty:netty-bom:pom:4.1.22.Final (absent): io.netty:netty-bom:pom:4.1.22.Final failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact io.netty:netty-bom:pom:4.1.22.Final from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: Could not build a validated path. @ org.infinispan:infinispan-bom:9.3.0.Final, /usr/local/examples/mavenrepo/org/infinispan/infinispan-bom/9.3.0.Final/infinispan-bom-9.3.0.Final.pom, line 754, column 22
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.6 (absent): org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.6 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: Could not build a validated path. @ org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:1.1.13.Final, /usr/local/examples/mavenrepo/org/jboss/arquillian/arquillian-bom/1.1.13.Final/arquillian-bom-1.1.13.Final.pom, line 206, column 25
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom:pom:2.0.0-alpha-10 (absent): org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom:pom:2.0.0-alpha-10 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom:pom:2.0.0-alpha-10 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: Could not build a validated path. @ org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:1.1.13.Final, /usr/local/examples/mavenrepo/org/jboss/arquillian/arquillian-bom/1.1.13.Final/arquillian-bom-1.1.13.Final.pom, line 224, column 25 at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build (DefaultProjectBuilder.java:208)


Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingException: 3 problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.infinispan:infinispan-parent:9.3.0.Final
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: The following artifacts could not be resolved: io.netty:netty-bom:pom:4.1.22.Final (absent): io.netty:netty-bom:pom:4.1.22.Final failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact io.netty:netty-bom:pom:4.1.22.Final from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: Could not build a validated path. @ org.infinispan:infinispan-bom:9.3.0.Final, /usr/local/examples/mavenrepo/org/infinispan/infinispan-bom/9.3.0.Final/infinispan-bom-9.3.0.Final.pom, line 754, column 22
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.6 (absent): org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.6 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom:pom:1.2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: Could not build a validated path. @ org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:1.1.13.Final, /usr/local/examples/mavenrepo/org/jboss/arquillian/arquillian-bom/1.1.13.Final/arquillian-bom-1.1.13.Final.pom, line 206, column 25
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom:pom:2.0.0-alpha-10 (absent): org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom:pom:2.0.0-alpha-10 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors:shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom:pom:2.0.0-alpha-10 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: Could not build a validated path. @ org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:1.1.13.Final, /usr/local/examples/mavenrepo/org/jboss/arquillian/arquillian-bom/1.1.13.Final/arquillian-bom-1.1.13.Final.pom, line 224, column 25

If we note in the above stack trace, it successfully downloads infinispan-bom and infinispan-core pom files from private repository, but for netty-bom it goes directly to the central repository which eventually leads to the PKIX path building failed error as the access to maven central is not allowed
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-bom/4.1.22.Final/netty-bom-4.1.22.Final.pom

Dependency Plugin Version: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8
Java version: 1.8.0_292
Am I missing anything here? seeking help to resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Which version of dependency plugin do you use? Do you bind version for this plugin in your project?

I would suggest to check the JDK version based on that: PKIX path building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException: Could not build a validated path ?

@SlawomirJaranowski org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8 this is the version , yes it is specified in the project

@khmarbaise jdk version is same as it was with mvn 3.0.3, Java version: 1.8.0_292

Update maven-dependency-plugin version to most recent version https://maven.apache.org/plugins/
